# python Temporary variable changing with actual variable ; snake game pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make snake game using pygame in python.
the `body` variable contains the coordinates of the body including head
in every iteration the head gets a new coordinate and the next one gets the previous location of the head and so on.
the function `change_angle` gives it new coordinate. so i tried storing the value of head in a temporary variable `prev_head` but its value is changing with the change of actual variable
right now i am using single assignment once its rectified i will use loop for the entire  length of the body

```py
prev_head = None
body = [[30, 55], [30, 56], [30, 57]]


# initailising pygame display
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((dispaly_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# functions


def square(snake):
    head = snake[0]
    snake_queue = snake[1:]
    size = 10
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green,
                     (head[0]*size, head[1]*size, size, size))

    for i in range(len(snake_queue)):
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white,
                         (snake_queue[i][0]*size, snake_queue[i][1]*size, size, size))


def change_angle(body, cor, direction):
    body[0][cor] = body[0][cor]+(direction)

    return body


def game_loop():
    global body, prev_head
    change = (1, -1)

    while True:
        time.sleep(lvl[2])
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    if change != (0, 1):
                        change = (0, -1)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    if change != (0, -1):
                        change = (0, 1)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    if change != (1, 1):
                        change = (1, -1)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    if change != (1, -1):
                        change = (1, 1)

        gameDisplay.fill(back)
        prev_head = body[0]
        body = change_angle(body, change[0], change[1])
        square(body)

        pygame.display.update()


game_loop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

> ```py
> prev_head = body[0]
> ```

then `prev_head` is not a copy of `body[0]`. `prev_head` and `body[0]` refer to the same list object.

If you change the content of `body[0]`

> ```py
> body[0][cor] = body[0][cor]+(direction)
> ```

then `prev_head` seems to change, too, because `body[0]` and `prev_head` refer to the same list obejct.

Use `[:]` to create a shallow copy of the inner list. (See [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)):

```py
prev_head = body[0][:]
```

Alternatively you can copy the inner list by `body[0].copy()`

Comment: thats really helpful. i have been doing it in other programs also getting similar problems .thanks